# Firebase and Swift for in loop

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase I have

```
 firebase app link  / data / vets
                             groomers
```

How can I make two `for in` loops (one for iterating vets, other for iterating groomers) in `.observeEventType()`

UPDATE:
I can't copy/paste all data in my Firebase because it's a secret but it looks like this.

```
data
     vets
          childKey
                   name: Some Name
                   address: Some Address
          childKey
                   name: Some Name
                   address: Some Address

      groomers
               childKey
                   name: Some Name
                   address: Some Address
               childKey
                   name: Some Name
                   address: Some Address
```

I am making pins on a map for every vet and groomer. So it is important for me to make for in loop in vets/groomers because I'm modeling new vets/groomers there which end up on a map. And it has to be like that because I have remove all annotations on the end of `observeSingleEventOfType()` because it has to be real-time map.

This is my initial code that was working great until I added groomers...

```
DataService.ds.refData.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let vetDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let vet = Vet(vetKey: key, dict: vetDict)
                        self.grabLoc(vet.address, city: vet.city, name: vet.name, displayAddress: vet.displayAddress, key: vet.vetKey, id: vet.id)
                    }


                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you paste your firebase structure? You can export it as a text file by going to your Firebase dashboard and selecting Export in the upper right corner. Then paste your current code so we can better understand the question. There's not enough data to fully understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("data").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("vets").children {
        print(child.key);
    }
    for child in snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("groomers").children {
        print(child.key);
    }
});
```